# How to remove specific lines from a text file?

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have a text file `F` containing text in multiple lines and another text file `L` which contains  list of numbers corresponding to lines in `F`
I would like to remove all the lines listed in `L` from `F`

In the example below:

```
cat F.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc

cat L.txt
1
3
```

I need a command which will remove lines `1` and `3` from `F.txt`, leaving only line 2, and save it in a new file `F_new.txt`:

```
cat F_new.txt
bbb
```

Comment: Please add your attempts to the question, even if they failed.

Comment: I was going to add more details on the failed attempts, but @bu5hman already solved my problem. Apparently I was using awk wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` just load the row numbers from the first file `NR==FNR` into an array `p[]` and then print from the second file `NR!=FNR` where the array element for that row doesn't exist `!p[FNR]`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[$1]=$1}
     NR!=FNR&&!p[FNR]' L.txt F.txt > F_New.txt

bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option, turning the contents of `L.txt` into a sequence of `d` commands for sed

```
printf '%dd\n' $(<L.txt) | sed -f - F.txt > F_New.txt
```

You could also use sed itself to do the transformation

```
sed 's/$/d/' L.txt | sed -f - F.txt > F_New.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cp F.txt F_new.txt
for i in $(sort -nr L.txt)
do
    sed -i "${i}d" F_new.txt
done
```